# How to verify http response via python, and add to list?

Tags: python, http

I am working on an assignment for work where my boss wants me to write a program to verify company domains exist with a certain HR system. This HR system has their name directly in the company's website URL. For example, ropeswings.bamboohr.com. I'm writing a program that checks those URLs and if the HTTP response is 200, my program adds them to a list. Once the program is working I'm going to output that list to a txt file.

My problem is the python request and logging the HTTP response properly. When I run this code with the name of a company that I know for a fact has this HR company, the list still outputs as empty. And I can't figure out where I went wrong. Any ideas?

```
import sys, re, csv

domains = []
bamboos = []

with open('clist.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        main = row[14][:-4]
        if main in domains:
            continue
        else:
            domains.append(main)
domains.pop(0)

for domain in domains:
    try: 
        request = requests.get('https://' + domain + '.bamboohr.com/login.php')
        if request.status_code == 200:
            bamboos.append(domain)
    except:
        continue    
print(bamboos)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound a little bit awkward, but I think you aren't importing the requests package within the module. Remember that requests is non a built-in class/object. Please, import it and try again.

Comment: Wow....I feel like the surprised Pikachu meme. I never caught that because it never gave me a traceback. Let's see how that works

Comment: Just tried it, and the program is not printing anything :/

Comment: Ok. Please, try to add an `Exception` after the except keyword. That will allow you to access the Exception in the except scope, so you can print it to the console and get more information regarding the error. The block should be something like
```except Exception:
    print(Exception)
    continue```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have not imported requests. Add `import requests` to your python file.

Once the code execution enters `try`, an error in try block will cause the execution to go to the `except` block. As, you are using `continue` statement in except, it wont raise any error and goes back to the for loop again resulting in an empty list. Your program maybe failing in `requests.get()`. You can also check this by adding a print in the beginning of except.

If `except` is not executed try to print the response code. If you would like to get the traceback errors if any, execute the file without try and except. This will give you an idea if there is something wrong with your code